# Runtime Error due to multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, multiprocessing

I am attempting to use the [Seq2Pat python library](https://fidelity.github.io/seq2pat/index.html#) for the first time. Everything seemed to install correctly for the library, Cython, and the compiler. When running a test script for the first time (seqPatMineTest.py) I am receiving this error. I'm not sure where to attempt to address this so any suggestion would be most appreciated. Here is the error:

```
C:\Users\timmy\OneDrive\Documents\Python For Everybody\Seq2Pat>seqPatMineTest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 114, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path
    run_name="__mp_main__")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\timmy\OneDrive\Documents\Python For Everybody\Seq2Pat\seqPatMineTest.py", line 37, in <module>
    results = seq2pat.get_patterns(min_frequency=2)
  File "C:\Users\timmy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sequential\seq2pat.py", line 526, in get_patterns
    thread.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 33, in __init__
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 143, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 136, in _check_not_importing_main
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.''')
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```